# Не загружается Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: ubuntu

Поставил на VMware Ubuntu 18.04. При загрузке сначала виснет на строке:

```
        Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
 [ OK ] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
```

Потом выдает

```
        Stopping CUPS Scheduler...
 [ OK ] Stopped CUPS Scheduler.
 [ OK ] Started CUPS Scheduler.
        Starting Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service...
 [ OK ] Started Network Manager Script Dispatcher Service.
```

И на конец виснет здесь:

```
        Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories...
 [ OK ] Starting Cleanup of Temporary Directories.
```

В чем может быть проблема?

**UPD**

Настройки машины:

```
Memory: 2gb
Processors: 1
HardDisk(SCSI): 80gb
Network Adapter: NAT
```

Comment: А если Alt+F2 ткнуть?

Comment: @andreymal повисло на `[ OK ] Started Run anacron Jobs`

Comment: @Rikitikitavi настройки машины какие?

Comment: @SeniorPomidor Обновил вопрос.

Comment: @Rikitikitavi попробуйте видеопамять побольше поставить